# Idiom for when someone relates two unrelated things

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom about someone who surprisingly relates **two** unrelated things in an unbelievable story?

"Cock and bull story" seems to be used mainly about complex stories told as an excuse (e.g., see examples provided [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+cock-and-bull+story)), and after all, it doesn't necessarily contain **two** unrelated things which have been surprisingly related: What matters is that the story is implausible.

The answer may be an idiom in the form of "He relates X with Y!" (for example "He relates pants with pandas!").

Comment: *apophenia* seems to be the nondeliberate counterpart of what the person in question is doing.

Comment: An _optimistic matchmaker_. A dealer in _pretentious metaphors_.

Answer (score 2):

**strange bedfellows**

> **bedfellow**
>
> —often used in the phrase **strange bedfellows** to describe an
> unlikely alliance of people or things [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strange%20bedfellows)
>
> *Polities and good architecture are strange bedfellows, but in Barcelona the marriage has worked.*

> A pair of people, things, or groups connected in a certain situation
> or activity but extremely different in overall characteristics,
> opinions, ideologies, lifestyles, behaviors, etc.
>
> *A notorious playboy musician and an ultra-conservative media pundit may be strange bedfellows, but the two are coming together all this month to bring a spotlight to suicide awareness.* [Farlex Dictionary
> of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/strange+bedfellows)

---

> ... including not only relatively well-known films like Mel Brook's
> *Young Frankenstein* (1974), but also some very **strange bedfellows** like *Abbott and Costello Meet Frankenstein* (1948), *Jesse James
> Meets Frankenstein's Daughter* (1966), and even *Frankenstein's Great
> Aunt Tillie* (1984). [Garry Gillard; *Empowering Readers: Ten
> Approaches to Narrative*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Empowering_Readers/mUn060vP7YkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strange%20bedfellows%22%20fable&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: _Chalk and cheese_ is another one that I've heard from Australians, though not Americans. Usually it's a measure - _as different as chalk and cheese_.

Comment: Chalk and Cheese is British English dating back to 14th century and still used.

Comment: Apples/oranges and chalk/cheese, although interesting, are both about contrasting/comparing two things per se, not making a story. My question is more about when you weave a story to relate the fact that, say, "oranges are round" to the fact that "apples are red"!

Comment: I've changed my first answer, "Comparing apples and oranges," now that I understand the question better.

Comment: I don't think *strange bedfellows* captures the unreliability of the story's provenance. Apples and oranges works for dissonant concepts, but not in the context of a confabulated or bull(sh*tted) story involving unrelated components.

Comment: If this unreliability is central to the concept, it isn't clear to me if/how it is related to the disparate elements being compared.

Comment: An 'unlikely marriage' also describes the situation ensuing, using the same metaphor. But it's the improbable-matchmaking aspect that I can't think of an idiomatic expression for.

Answer (score 0):

["Difference between heaven and earth"](http://www.standardmandarin.com/idiom/literally-a-gulf-between-heaven-and-earth)

This is a famous Chinese idiom. It means that the two things in consideration really couldn't have been further apart.

Answer (score 0):

This concept (weaving a story where you compare two dissimilar things) is *very* specific and simply doesn't have a dedicated idiom in English, you'll need to use two: "That cock and bull story doesn't make any sense! They're like apples and oranges!" Or something to that effect.